# How do I know if my web camera is linked to Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, skype, webcam

Ubuntu 12.04.

I own a Samsung NC10, with a 1.3 Mega Pixel integrated digital motion camera. (That I copied from the [Specs](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP-NC10-KA02UK-techspecs) page.)

But how do I know if it's linked up? (Can I use a program or something?)

If so, what if it's not linked up? How can I link it up?

Sorry for the multiple questions, but my web camera is quite important as I might get Skype.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [lsusb](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-do-i-list-all-usb-devices/) to list devices, assuming the camera is listed you could use [cheese](http://projects.gnome.org/cheese/) (it should be in the repos) to test that it is working